# unable to find a MessageBodyReader

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs, resteasy

I have this interface:

```
 @Path("inbox")
public interface InboxQueryResourceTest {

    @POST
    @Path("{membershipExternalId}/query")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces("multipart/mixed")
    public MultipartOutput query(@PathParam("membershipExternalId") final String membershipExternalId,
                             @QueryParam("page") @DefaultValue("0") final int page,
                             @QueryParam("pageSize") @DefaultValue("10") final int pageSize,
                             @QueryParam("sortProperty") final List<String> sortPropertyList,
                             @QueryParam("sortReversed") final List<Boolean> sortReversed,
                             @QueryParam("sortType") final List<String> sortTypeString,
                             final InstanceQuery instanceQuery) throws IOException;
}
```

I have implemented the method to return a MultipartOutput.
I am posting an xml query from Fiddler and i receive the result without any problem.

BUT i have done an integration test for the same interface, i send the same objects and i put the response like:

```
final MultipartOutput multiPartOutput = getClient().query(getUserRestAuth(), 0, 25, null, null, null, instanceQuery);
```

But here, so from integration tests, i receive a strange error:

> Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type multipart/mixed;boundary="74c5b6b4-e820-452d-abea-4c56ffb514bb" and type class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartOutput

Anyone has any ideea why only in integration tests i receive this error?

PS: Some of you will say that i do not send application/xml as ContentType but multipart, which of course is false because the objects are annotated with the required @XmlRootElement etc, otherways neither the POST from Fiddler would work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
ResteasyProviderFactory providerFactory = ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance();
providerFactory.registerProvider(org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MimeMultipartProvider.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are including in classpath the corresponding resteasy addon for multipart encoding? (esteasy-multipart-provider).

Comment: In client classpath as well? I believe the error is because the client resteasy proxy does not have a MessageBodyReader registered that can handle multipart/mixed. If you are using resteasy 1.2 or superior then it's enough to include in client's classpath the previous mentioned jar, in case of a resteasy version <1.2 then you have to do as Chandru writes in client's code. For your integration tests are you using two separate VMs or you run client and server in the same?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this method to your test class.  This would register the default built-in providers which are already registered on your server.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void registerProviders() {
    ResteasyProviderFactory providerFactory = ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance();
    RegisterBuiltin.register(providerFactory);
}
```

Comment: `RegisterBuiltin.register(providerFactory)` will be invoked by default during `ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance()` invoсation