# Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/octet-stream

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I'm struggling with an REST-Service written with JAX-RS.

I want to create and bind a client with the following code:

```
final String DEFAULT_RESOURCE_URL = "http://someURL:8180/";

    try {
        ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build().register(ClientResponseLoggingFilter.class);

        ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(DEFAULT_RESOURCE_URL).path(
                "service/document/getdrawingbrowser/{documentId}/{documentType}/{partDocumentId}/{documentVersion}/{userName}");

        HashMap<String, Object> keyValuesMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        keyValuesMap.put("documentId", "xxxx");
        keyValuesMap.put("documentType", "yyy");
        keyValuesMap.put("partDocumentId", "000");
        keyValuesMap.put("documentVersion", "000");
        keyValuesMap.put("userName", "user");

        Builder responseBuilder = target.resolveTemplates(keyValuesMap).request();
        Response response = responseBuilder.get();


        if (response.getStatus() == 200) {

            byte[][] documents = response.readEntity(byte[][].class);
            for (int i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
                displayProperties(documents[i]);
            }
        } else {
            Object entity = response.getEntity();
            System.out.println(entity);
        }

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The REST-Service responds correctly I guess:

```
status: 200
date: Mon Sep 14 10:53:02 CEST 2015
last-modified: null
location: null
headers:
    Connection :keep-alive, 
    Content-Disposition :attachment; filename=someFile.pdf, 
    Content-Type :application/octet-stream, 
    Date :Mon, 14 Sep 2015 08:53:02 GMT, 
    Server :WildFly/8, 
    Transfer-Encoding :chunked, 
    X-Powered-By :Undertow/1, 
media-type: application
```

But in line 102 `byte[][] documents = response.readEntity(byte[][].class);` I'm getting an `javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException` which says:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/octet-stream and type class [[B
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientReaderInterceptorContext.throwReaderNotFound(ClientReaderInterceptorContext.java:39)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.getReader(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:73)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:50)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:59)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:53)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.readFrom(ClientResponse.java:248)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:181)
at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.readEntity(BuiltResponse.java:217)
at DocumentTest.main(DocumentTest.java:102)
```

I have tried several .jar files and some approaches from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425369/unable-to-find-a-messagebodyreader) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175564/unable-to-find-a-messagebodyreader-of-content-type-application-json-and-type-cla), but sadly, none of them worked out...

Any ideas?

Comment: Why `byte[][]`? You're requesting a single document and you get a single document in the reply. How is the code supposed to know how to split the reply into multiple arrays of bytes? (I guess it works if you use just `byte[].class`)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change you `Content-Type` to `application/pdf`.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no access to the server, therefore I can not change anything regarding the respond!